# Meteor. Prevent multiple inserts from console

Tags: javascript, meteor, spam-prevention

Let's imagine I'm a bad man, and I see that website uses Meteor. 
I search for a collection description in js files (let it be "Posts"), and write in console

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
  Posts.insert({title:'foobar'});
}
```

And we got the DB full of trash. 
How to prevent this? Registration isn't much problem for such attack, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[allow rules](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow)**.

First remove the insecure package:

```
meteor remove insecure
```

Then make some rules (e.g you have to be logged in) & in the example below you can only modify your own documents.

**Server side code**

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    return doc.owner === userId;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return doc.owner === userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: I recommend using deny rules to check for user existence, user equality to doc owner, and as a rate limiting measure, previous doc's createdate being older than eg 30 seconds, number of docs in the past 24 hours less than eg 50.

Comment: Yup I should probably add this in, for the rate-limiting we would have to limit it per connection. Are we able to access the connection/id/instance from the allow callbacks? If it is per connection? would that no be a better idea?

Comment: Actually its better to check from the timestamp like you suggested I think. This is if the OP wants it this way? @user3489952

Comment: Yes, checking timestamp is exactly what I didn't think about.. Thanks guys. And explain please about rate-limiting per connection, if it's possible, please ))

Comment: Connections are not currently available to allow/deny, follow this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/LUBfaUtfo7c